# Не высвечиваются подсказки в Visual Studio (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity3d, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

у меня возникла проблема
У меня не светятся подсказки в VS коде
Я знаю что вы скажете что мне нужно скачать нагрузку из VS Installer
или же поставить в настройках Preferces - VS 2019
Но это не помогает, очень прошу сказать возможную причину, и как её решить...

Comment: Mac OS?........

Comment: Windows 10.....